# How to share packages with other ubuntu systems?

Tags: apt, apt-mirror

I have a host Ubuntu 13.10 system in which I am installing packages via `apt-get install`

Now there are many virtual machines which run on top of this host machine.

I want these virtual machines to install from already downloaded packages by the host machine and skip going to the internet first to save my time.

I know I can create a local `apt-mirror` and copy a full Ubuntu repo to my host machine, but I don't want all of those packages.

I want to share only which I need and I want to download only once in my host machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to do this with [apt-cacher](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Apt-Cacher-Server).

It allowed a network of Ubuntu machines to get their updates from a local server, thus simultaneously saving external bandwidth and speeding updates/installs. In your case you'd set the software sources of the VM guests to point at the apt-cacher proxy server, possibly running on the VM host.

Haven't used it for a couple of years, though, so don't know if it still works. Good luck!

Comment: Thank , you i think this is what i need. I will read its tutorial and install it. Thanks